# Changing a dropdown value results in: Cannot read property entityState of undefined

Tags: angularjs, breeze, dropdown

I'm working on an existing AngularJS app where I need to add a new view.  In the new view, there is a dropdown which triggers this error every time the value is changed.  The dropdown loads all the data correctly.  It's only when the value is changed that something goes wrong.

```
<select class="form-control form-controls input-sm" ng-model="vm.retailer.state" ng-options="state.code as state.name for state in vm.states track by state.code">
    <option value="">-- Select a State --</option>
</select>
```

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'entityState' of undefined
```

Drilling into the first line on the stack trace, the error is happening here:

```
https://localhost:44398/bower_components/breezejs/breeze.debug.js:5284:20
```

It's inside this method:

```
function setNpValue(context, rawAccessorFn)
```

Here's the 'context' object.  It all looks good:

```
context: Object
entityAspect: EntityAspect
newValue: "AL"
oldValue: null
parent: Retailer__Model
property: NavigationProperty
propertyName: "state"
__proto__: Object
```

Down inside the method is where the error is happening.

```
if (newValue != null) {
    var newAspect = newValue.entityAspect;
    if (entityManager) {
        if (newAspect.entityState.isDetached()) {
            if (!entityManager.isLoading) {
                entityManager.attachEntity(newValue, EntityState.Added);
            }
```

NewValue is accurately reflecting the new value I selected ("AL" in this case), so it is not null.  However, on the next line down, newValue.entityAspect is undefined, so newAspect also ends up being undefined. As a result, when we get to this line:

```
newAspect.entityState.isDetached()
```

The error occurs.

I can post the entire controller for the view of where the dropdown exists, if that will help.  But it seems like overkill. Looking for any help I can get.  I'm pretty new to Angular.

**EDIT / UPDATE:**

I thought I had found the solution.  As the solution to this question:

[Dropdown in AngularJS has Correct Text, but Wrong Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786086/dropdown-in-angularjs-has-correct-text-but-wrong-value)

I had added "track by state.code" to the dropdown.  In trying to troubleshoot THIS problem, I removed it.  After a refresh, this error went away.  WAHOO!  But my joy was short lived.  A short time later, the error came back.  And now I'm back to square one.

Comment: How are your vm.states array and vm.retailer object being populated?  Is it possible that the vm.retailer is a breeze entity that is expecting an entity for the state property, but you are setting it to a string?  Breeze is pretty smart about the entities that it instantiates, so I'd guess the problem is in some of the object assignments somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, you are on the right track.  newValue should be an object, but instead it's a string.  I honestly do not know why.  I can't find where this is being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was able to solve this problem.  Only it has created another. The problem here was in how I was building my dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control form-controls input-sm" ng-model="vm.retailer.state" ng-options="state.code as state.name for state in vm.states track by state.code">
    <option value="">-- Select a State --</option>
</select>
```

I changed it to:

```
<select class="form-control form-controls input-sm" ng-model="vm.retailer.state" ng-options="state as state.name for state in vm.states">
    <option value="">-- Select a State --</option>
</select>
```

And this error went away.  But the thing is, I had added made this change to solve the problem I posted about here:

[Dropdown in AngularJS has Correct Text, but Wrong Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786086/dropdown-in-angularjs-has-correct-text-but-wrong-value)

So now I'm back to trying to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well when I updated angular from 1.3.x to 1.4.x.  When I converted back to angular 1.3.x, it went away.  I assume there is something in the Breeze Angular Service that was broken by angular and has not been fixed by breeze yet.